Scheduled Tasks in Spring Boot
I am currently implementing a small project and need your advice. I am looking for a task scheduler which I can give a date and time at runtime of my Java and Spring-Boot environment, so that it executes a method of my choice at this time. Furthermore, it should offer the possibility to view already scheduled tasks in order to pause or stop them if necessary. It should also be possible to stop or pause a task while it is running. The important thing is that new tasks can be added or removed at any time during runtime.
Do anyone know a suitable library for this use case or what would be the best way to implement this?
Looking forward to your experience! Thank 

You may be able to use ScheduledExecutorService/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and call cancel() on the submitted tasks/futures. But getting all submitted tasks in a way you can cancel them may be difficult/something you might need to handle yourself.

Alternatively, How to query the scheduled jobs from Quartz scheduler? and How to cancel a scheduled Quartz job in Spring could be useful with Quartz.

I think you should implement this, because the meaning of "pausing/stopping scheduled/running tasks" completely depend on what these tasks are and how you intend them to behave. The ScheduledExecutorService will definitely help you to invoke the right methods at the right time but you probably want to do the housekeeping of these tasks and defining what it means to stop (rollback needed?) or pause (what if a DB connection was open? Will it remain open until further notice?) them.
